# Fetching and setting a hidden default value for ReactHookForm with ReactQuery and Zod validation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, zod, tanstackreact-query

I have a form using the ReactHookForm, ReactQuery and Zod for validation. I want to associate the current user with the form, so when they submit the record in the DB is associated with them. This is my first time really using ReactHookForm and ReactQuery so please bare with the ugliness of my code. This code console.log's the user_id, but clicking "submit" to create a form does not do anything, the page does not submit anything. It also seems like it's re-rendering something many times - the id console.log's every few seconds

It works without the hidden id value logic.

Am I passing the fetched value to the hidden input correctly, is there a different way to do this? The code:

```
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as z from 'zod';

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Textarea } from '@/components/ui/textarea';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

import { useState } from 'react';

import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

import axios from 'axios';

const profileFormSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string()
    .min(2, {
      message: 'Username must be at least 2 characters.',
    })
    .max(320, {
      message: 'Username must not be longer than 320 characters.',
    })
    .email(),
  title: z.string({
    required_error: 'Please provide a title for your e-mail.',
  }),
  content: z.string().max(10000).min(4),
  can_share: z.boolean(),
  user_id: z.string().nullable(),
});

type ProfileFormValues = z.infer<typeof profileFormSchema>;

type Id = { id: number };

async function fetchUser() {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/get-user');
  console.log('id:', res.data.data);
  //  parse against the schema
  return profileFormSchema.parse({ id: res.data.data });
}

// This can come from your database or API.
const defaultValues: Partial<ProfileFormValues> = {
  can_share: true,
};

export default function Page() {
  // TODO: redirect if no user detected

  // console.log(user);
  // if (!user) {
  //   redirect('/login');
  // }

  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const form = useForm<ProfileFormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(profileFormSchema),
    defaultValues,
    mode: 'onChange',
  });

  async function onSubmit(data: ProfileFormValues) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    const res = await fetch('/api/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(async (res) => {
      const json = await res.json();
      if (json.status === 201) {
        toast.success('Template created!');
        console.log(json);
        setUrl(json.data);
      }
    });
  }
  //TODO: hardcoded website url
  const handleCopy = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      `https://rallymail.vercel.app/template/${url}`
    );
    toast.success('Copied to clipboard.');
  };

  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['initial-users'],
    queryFn: () => fetchUser(),
    initialData: defaultValues,
  });

  if (data) {
    return (
      <Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className='my-10 space-y-8'
        >
          <FormField
            name='user_id'
            control={form.control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <input type='hidden' {...field} value={data.user_id as any} />
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name='email'
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Receiver&apos;s e-mail</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder='shadcn' {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>
                  The e-mail address that this template will be addressed to.
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
```

GitHub repository:
https://github.com/polooner/rallymail/blob/dev/app/create/page.tsx